# An ssrs problem:how to hide/show the drop down list of the report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a SSRS 2008 report in which i have created 5 parameter so that whenever i preview the report it show 5 drop down to select values based on which report is generated.Now i want that when i preview  the report there should be a check box like something so that i am able to show or hide the drop down list.

Answer (score 0):

you can hide the entire panel with parameters, in this way as shown in Figure

[image]

Comment: Could you please tell how can i do this that means process to do it.and also the resources where i can find some more knowledge to this .

Comment: I just to turn off/on some drop down when it appear while i am previewing the report so that user can not select any value from this drop down.

Comment: I dont want to hide the panel of the parameter.please understand my requirement.

Comment: in the panel can not disable user to select predefined parameters for the report, but it is possible to do a trick with a sub-report. 
I'd made so that the first start of the report choose the parameters and then get a blank report but with a link, click on that link would be made sub-report with those parameters, after the sub-report modes the user can not choose these parameters because these parameters will remain the first report.